# Zend + Doctrine Error on Table relationship

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine

What is the best practice of joining table (left join) syntax in doctrine?

I have this code:

```
    $userTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Application_Model_User');

    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('u.*')
            ->from('Application_Model_User2 u')
            ->leftJoin('u.Application_Model_User2 p');

    echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

but what I get is this error:

```
    Message: Unknown relation alias Application_Model_User2
```

PS: Application_Model_User and Application_Model_User2 extends the generated model by the doctrine.

Does someone have any idea with regards to this error?

Comment: Do you have specified a `relations` item in your doctrine schema ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using associations in entities to make your life easier. You could achieve the result you are trying to achieve really easily.

[Basic information about associations](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) and [a bit more in depth](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html).